# Make MX records point to two servers (gmail and hostgator server)

Tags: email, mx-record

My website is hosted on Hostgator and some of users use gmail mail service and some other use POP3 service, so I'm not sure if it's possible to make MX records to point to both these servers (gmail and POP3)? for example: making inf@example.com used by gmail while gm@example.com used by POP3

Comment: So you’ve got your question answered about pointing MX records to two different services, but nobody really asked what it was you were even talking about? Your statement about some users using gmail and some using pop3 doesn’t make any sense. One is an email service and the other is a mail delivery protocol. Gmail works with pop3 as most any other mail service does. All email addresses for example.com would be hosted on the same servers regardless of how users retrieve that email, so somewhere there is a misunderstanding about the technology.

Answer (score 5):

MX records to multiple providers? No.

However, Google has a [dual delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650) option, you point your mx records to Google and send copies to any other providers (can be multiple). Only works with gsuite/apps, not free gmail, however you do not need to have licenses for all mailboxes hosted at other servers ( for example, corporate users can have full apps but temps could use Zimbra or something free on premise)

> You set up dual delivery to deliver email messages to 2 or more
>   inboxes. For example, users can receive messages in a Gmail inbox and
>   a non-Gmail inbox, such as a Microsoft Exchange inbox or an archiving
>   server.

Answer (score 4):

not possible.. DNS only knows hostname and what IP(s) it's mapped to.

You'd have to do that on the mail server side. You'd need control over the mailserver to setup forwards for users.  Forwarding can be done via SMTP or LMTP.

All mail comes into the same mail server.  On that mail server, you need to devise which messages are forwarded to which mail storage.  For example, forward `gmail-user@example.com` to `gmail-user-alias@gmail.example.com`, 
where the `@gmail.example.com` subdomain entry is configured to forward to gmail.